# Check status processes, services in Unix, Linux with Java

Tags: java, linux, unix

I have codes to check status of Windows Services, like:

```
   Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = r.exec("net use \\\\"+server+"\\ipc$ /user:"+domain+"\\"+user+" "+password);
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sc query "+service);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                if (line.trim().startsWith("STATE"))
                {
                    if (line.trim().substring(line.trim().indexOf(":") + 1,line.trim().indexOf(":") + 4).trim().equals("1"))
                        System.out.println("Stopped");
                    else if (line.trim().substring(line.trim().indexOf(":") + 1,line.trim().indexOf(":") + 4).trim().equals("2"))
                        System.out.println("Startting....");
                    else if (line.trim().substring(line.trim().indexOf(":") + 1,line.trim().indexOf(":") + 4).trim().equals("3"))
                        System.out.println("Stopping....");
                    else if (line.trim().substring(line.trim().indexOf(":") + 1,line.trim().indexOf(":") + 4).trim().equals("4"))
                        System.out.println("Running");
                }
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
```

Now, I want to write codes to check status of Linux, Unix Processes, Services like above.

Thanks,

Comment: So what's the problem? Don't be vague in your question. (And definitely don't try to be manipulate anyone into writing your code for you.)

Comment: Now, I want to write codes to check status of Linux, Unix Processes, Services like above. Who can help me?

Comment: Help you with what? Be specific.

Comment: The Codes above check Windows process in another computer. It can't check with Linux, Unix Operator, so I have to write other codes to check status Linux, Unix Process, Services.

Answer (score 0):

You can interface with the linux command `ps` (see `man ps` for more info) to see the processes.

For services, this is distribution-dependent; many modern distributions use [systemd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd), some still use init scripts. You need to research the way services are managed for whatever distributions you want to support.